# Change color of repeat single character using NSAttributeString?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scenario to change the color of single repeat characters '#' in a string just like as image shown below.
I m using this code.

```
    let textTag = lblNewsTag.text
    let range = (textTag! as NSString).rangeOfString("#")
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:textTag!)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor() , range: range)
    lblTag.attributedText = attributedString
```

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: In a nutshell... match the characters with a regex (or by any other means), get the **range** of each match and apply the desired attributes.

Comment: I have not implemented yet.

Comment: See updated Question @NiravD

Comment: `rangeOfString:` returns the FIRST parameter found. So your code should colorize only the first one. Use Regex, or simply look how to "loop" with `rangeOfString:` (plenty of question on SO about that).

Comment: Plz give me the proper answer @Larme,@Alladinian

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Larme beat me, Solution provided by him its perfect for your case.